# C++ SDL sprite at negative position

Tags: c++, position, sdl, sprite

I'm making a platform game in SDL and C++ on where there is a camera that moves the level when I move in certain positions. It works great, except for one thing. Levels use sprites to create blocks, and when I move the character forward, each element in the map moves backwards, creating the sensation of movement. So the pipe characters below would be the screen, and the S's the sprites, when I start the game

```
|.S..SS.|S..S
|.S...S.|.S.
```

Now if I move my character close to the right of the screen, the map would start moving each element backwards. It should look like this:

```
.S.|.SS.S..|S
.S.|..S..S.|
```

The problem is that everything represented before the first pipe (start of the screen)
is set at a negative position, so SDL instead of placing the elements in a negative X position, leaves them at x position 0 (refuses negative numbers). How can I get SDL to place the elements at negative positions? With this done, my camera would work perfectly.

Comment: SDL 1 or 2? And please provide a minimum (but complete and compileable) code sample along with a screenshot which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: From what I remember, SDL 1.2 doesn't allow you to use negative coordinates. You can instead put your camera somewhere off in the distance and use that as your 'starting position'.

Comment: @remyabel You can certainly blit into negative coordinates with sdl 1.2. and the surface will get clipped properly.